# Optimizing: replace value of known and solve. Python

Tags: python

I am writing a minimizing function for a single variable function. I want to create a 'xmin' array containing the values of x that replaced in the Second derivative make the second derivative greater than 0.

The code seems to be giving an error when calling 'xmin'. I do not know how to replace the values of the unknown 'x' with the optimizing values.

This is what I tried:

```
   from sympy import Symbol
   import numpy as np


   from sympy import solve

   x = Symbol('x')
   def fun(x):
       return x**2 

   First = fun(x).diff(x)
   Second = First.diff(x)

   xopt = solve(First, x)
   xmin = solve(Second, x=xopt)
   xmin = [i for i in xmin if i > 0]


   print('First derivative:\n', First)
   print('Second derivative:\n', Second)
   print('Optimal points:\n', xopt)
   print('Minimum:\n',xmin)
   print('End')
```